# Can't get user birthday with Google Play services API

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

**EDIT**

After a new try I finally got my birthday. I didn't change the implementation. I guess it took a few hours for the changes in my Google Plus profile to propagate, making my birthday public. A bit more than expected. Now I'm wondering whether I can ask this permission (birthday) when the user sign in, without the need of the birthday to be public.

As suggested by this information in the [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) :

> For additional profile data that might be available, see
>   GoogleSignInAccount. Note that any of the profile fields can be null,
>   depending on which scopes you requested and what information the
>   user's profile includes.

**Initial POST**

I would like to get the birthdays of a user after he signed in Google Plus. Being not familiar with Google APIs in general, I'm wondering whether my implementation makes some sense or not. Right now, I'm just trying to get my own birthday from my Google account linked to my device.

**Here is what I did.** I followed the steps from [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) for the sign in procedure. In addition to OAuth, I added the Google Plus dependency in gradle:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'

In my `Activity`, there is a button to sign in Google Plus.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME), new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN),new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();


loginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
```

After the initial sign in, I try to connect to the Google Play Services.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
           }
    }
}
```

Once connected, I try to fetch the birthday of the user.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        addGoogleProfile(currentPerson); //Add the user to a list of persons
        refreshListView(); //update the listView
        Log.d(TAG, "Current person: name=" + currentPerson.getDisplayName() + ", has birthday = " + (currentPerson.hasBirthday() ? "yes, it is" + currentPerson.getBirthday() : "no"));
    }
```

**Problem**

The **birthday is never set and always appears to be null**. Other data such as the name and profile image are accessible. I didn't find much information on the different [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes). I'm more familiar with Facebook API where the permissions are more explicitly requested upon login.

Any idea on what I am missing ?

Ho and I set my birthday field as "public" of the associated Google account.

Cheers

Comment: [`Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/v1/people?hl=en) is already deprecated. Use the new version implementation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. However, I don't understand how to get additional information. From https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount, it seems only a few fields are available.

Comment: You may find the possible values of Scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes). [PLUS_LOGIN](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes#PLUS_LOGIN) and [PROFILE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes.html#PROFILE) is worth looking for.

Comment: What I'm looking for is an API to access https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#methods

Answer (score 0):

Dear you can only getting the following information :-

```
mePerson.getId()
mePerson.getDisplayName()
mePerson.getImage().getUrl()
mePerson.getUrl()
```

Comment: Hey. Are you sure about that ? I mean, from https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount it seems that we can still request Scopes to get additional information. But I can't figure out how to do it though...

Comment: I'm Sure because your Gmail profile doesn't containing Birth date info on basic information

Answer (score 0):

We can get the birthday of a user from gmail, but for that the user needs to have public visibility of the birthday.

Follow these steps:

1. Login to gmail and go to: https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/birthday?hl=en&pli=1
2. Click on "Manage sharing settings" and set birthday to public
3. Add scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login